# Typo3 Neos TypoScript not found

Tags: exception, typoscript, neoscms

I intalled typo3 neos and changed the layout "For this page only" to LandingPage. Afterwards I saw this error

```
Exception while rendering
landingPage:
No "landingPage" TypoScript object found. Please make sure to define one in your TypoScript configuration. (20140116115503dac096)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open [...]Sites/Your.Package/Resources/Private/TypoScript/Library/Roots.ts2 and add the following code:

```
// Special page layout with less navigation components
landingPage < page
landingPage.body {
    // Hide breadcrumb on landing pages
    parts.breadcrumb >
    landingPage = ${true}
}
```

Now the UI should load again.